# How to change the voice of Google Assistant when configured with more than one language? (Android 13)

Tags: languages, voice-command, google-assistant

Android 13 Google Assistant using English and Spanish languages. Opened the Google app, tap my profile, Settings, Google Assistant, English (United States) was already listed and español (Estados Unidos) was then added. Then selected “assistant voice and speech output” and from there I can select the voice that I want to use, but only for English. The option to change the Spanish voice is not available.

Had to remove English leaving only Spanish and then I was able to select the Spanish voice, but after adding the English language back, all I get is the option to change the English voice but not Spanish.

How can I select the voice for English and the voice for Spanish without having to remove one of the languages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of current writing (November 2022), **the settings for "Assistant voice and speech output" only affect *the primary language***. Note that *the primary language is the first language in the settings.*

There are 2 known ways to change the primary language:

- **Use "*change the language to <language>*" voice command** to switch the primary language, or
- **Change the first language from the settings**, but it will remove the second language if it's the same language, thus not really different than removing and re-adding it back.

---

*Note: The "Assistant voice and speech output" settings won't automatically refresh when the language is changed, the user needs to navigate back and reopen the settings to see the change.*